# AJAX — sending JSON without URLencoding

Tags: json, ajax, post, serialization, urlencode

**OBJECTIVE & BACKGROUND**

Compare two samples of text. These text samples are descriptions of products. Sample 1 is grabbed from a textarea in a form. Sample 1 is sent via AJAX to another file to be compared with Sample 2, which is grabbed from a database.

I am attempting to send as a JSON object because I assumed that would allow me to workaround sending URLencoded data in a plain POST / GET request.

**ISSUE**

When I send Sample 1 via AJAX in a JSON object it is being URLencoded with `+` for spaces, etc ... I need the text to be sent "as is" so that it can be compared. URLdecoding will not work since there might truly be `+` and other characters that are part of the true Sample 1.

**QUESTION**

How do I send Sample 1 without URLencoding the data?

**CODE**

```
        // we need the product id and description
        var pid = $("input[name='pid']").val();
        var descr = $("textarea[name='descr']").val();
        // put in a json object so we can see the real data
        var $obj = {
            "pid": pid,
            "descr": descr // Sample 1
        }
        // make the call and return the promise
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'request_file.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: $obj
        });
```

Comment: If you want to send JSON to the server than update the `$.ajax()` _`contentType`_ property to be: `application/json`. Also note, that I believe PHP will not populate the data in the `$_POST` superglobal. You'll have to read it in from standard input: `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `$.ajax` API,

```
contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
```

So by default it will be sent as url encoded only. Update the AJAX call as follows by setting the right parameter.

```
 return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType :'application/json',
            url: 'request_file.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: $obj
        });
```

The `contentType` parameter typically takes an MIME type as value. It is always the case to set the right MIME type for the usecase while sending the request, as well as using the **same** MIME type to read the data from request in the backend.

You can refer [here for various MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) that are available.